# Property 'result' does not exist on type 'void'. ?

Tags: angular

I have this method in .ts :

```
  search(event) {
     this.autocompletedata.forEach(function(entry) {
         this.result.push(entry['items'].filter(a=>a['item']));
     });

     console.log(this.result,'result');
 }
```

But i can not use `this.result`, but i don't know why. When i declare `let result` i can use, but this.result im getting this error. Any suggestion ? Somehow `this.result` is not visible inside method or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you create a privat function inside your forEach. The scope inside this function is different. If you use an arrow function, the scope stays the same and you are able to use `this.result`.

```
search(event) {
     this.autocompletedata.forEach((entry) => {
         this.result.push(entry['items'].filter(a=>a['item']));
     });

     console.log(this.result,'result');
}
```

Comment: that's it..tnx i will accept your answer because you are first :)

Answer (score 2):

`this.` won't behave as you expect inside functions declared with `function(entry) {`

If you change it to

```
(entry) => {
```

you'll get the desired behavior.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions